# When would Earth's Moon's gravity take over?

Tags: gravity, planets, stability

At which point would an object stop being pulled from Earth and towards the moon? Could a light weight rope be tethered to the moon with the object over on Earth's gravity's side? Can it be done and what would prevent it on a physically?

Comment: @count_to_10 that line doesn't matter can an object be tethered to the moon in that way?

Comment: Hi Jen, No, I don't think any rope or carbon nanotube is strong enough to even make it upwards for more than a few miles, maybe 6 times more on the moon cos of the lower gravity. It's a good idea though.

Comment: Please could you state what effort you have made to solve this problem. Why ideas do you have? What calculations have you made? This is a site for students/researchers/academics of physics and astronomy. We expect to see some effort. We do not do calculations for you.

Comment: You're always being pulled towards the moon. You just can't feel it because you're so far away. The farther you get from Earth and closer to the moon, the more of a pull you'll experience.

Comment: not homework just interesting unanswered questions.

Comment: @sammygerbil a simple yes or no is fine. Not a down vote or homework tag or a vote to close. If you cant contribute its ok

Comment: @count_to_10 a type of nylon rope can hold its on weight up to 42 miles. 9 times that on the moon. One company claimed their rope unrated, can hold 2500 tons and can stretch 120 miles on its own weight if built.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point you are looking for is called a [Lagrange Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point).  In particular, I believe the one you are looking for is L1, which is between the two bodies.  A Lagrange Point is a point where the forces of gravity from the two bodies sum to exactly the forces needed to remain in orbit.  An object which is put at a Lagrange Point will appear to stay at that position relative to the objects.

L1 of the Earth-moon system [happens to be](http://www.ottisoft.com/Activities/Lagrange%20point%20L1.htm) 326054 km from the center of the Earth.  It's not too popular for use by spacecraft because it is unstable (objects tend to fall into one gravity well or the other unless they are stabilized there), but it is useful for you when considering the point where the objects start to feel the pull of the moon more than they feel the pull of the Earth.

As for the rope trick, your theory is sound, but the practical application isn't there.  The length from the moon to the L1 point is far too long to permit any known material to work.  The forces would simply snap the rope in two, though that doesn't discount the possibility that future material science advancements wont change that.